# Why does MinGW-w64 generate 32-bit binaries?

Tags: c++, g++, mingw-w64

I'm using the MinGW-w64 version tagged as `x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0`. When running `g++ --version`, I see this:

```
g++.exe (x86_64-posix-seh-rev0, Built by MinGW-W64 project) 8.1.0
```

From my understanding, this version of g++ should generate 64-bit binaries by default.

The compiler command is like this:

```
g++.exe -std=c++17 -g main.cpp -o main.exe
```

However, if `main.cpp` looks like this:

```
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    std::cout << sizeof(long);
    return 0;
}
```

It prints `4` instead of `8`. I tried using a `-m64` compiler flag, but it changed nothing.

What am I doing wrong, and how to fix this?

Comment: `sizeof(long)` does not define if binary is 32 or 64 bitm - see https://stackoverflow.com/a/589685/432358 and for LLP64 de-facto standard

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does the C++ standard state the size of int, long type to be?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/589575/what-does-the-c-standard-state-the-size-of-int-long-type-to-be)

Comment: @AlanBirtles, the link @Slava posted is more relevant I think, considering we're talking about different de-facto standards on various platforms. The same code I posted above was returning `8` when built on Linux, hence the misinterpretation of the observed behavior on Windows. Remy's answer is at the same time the best option to determine whether the binary is a 64-bit one.

Comment: err, that is the post that Slava linked to?

Comment: @AlanBirtles, hm, yes, indeed. Not the top answer though. Still, I stand corrected.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`long` is not guaranteed to be 64 bits in size in a 64bit executable. In fact, [on Windows, `long` is always 32 bits under both x86 and x64](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/data-type-ranges?view=vs-2019). Use `long long` or `__int64` or `int64_t` if you need a 64 bit integer.  If you just want to check if your executable is compiled for 32-bit vs 64-bit, use `sizeof(void*)` instead.

Comment: Upvoted. If `sizeof(void*)` returns 4, then it is 32 bits. If it returns 8 then it is 64 bits.